# Assign results of a bash command to a variable in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to get this shell script to work in `make`:

```
$ VERSION=$(echo 'ThisBuild / version := "1.20"' | grep -e 'This.*version' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
$ echo $VERSION
1.20
```

`make`:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

`Makefile`:

```
version:

    VERSION=$(echo 'ThisBuild / version := "1.20"' | grep -e 'This.*version' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') && \
    echo "VERSION: ${VERSION}"
```

Doesn't work:

```
$ make version
VERSION= && \
echo "VERSION: "
VERSION:
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass `$` to the shell you have to escape it from make, by doubling it: `$$`.

```
version:
        VERSION=$$(echo 'ThisBuild / version := "1.20"' | grep -e 'This.*version' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') && \
        echo "VERSION: $${VERSION}"
```

Otherwise, make will think that you're referencing a make variable and expand it.